# Ubuntu Windows10 dual boot problem

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, mouse, login-screen, windows-10

I had Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 10. Both used to work well. I mainly used Ubuntu. I remember last time I booted into Windows 10 was a few months ago and there was no problem.

A few days ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 (not sure it this is the reason of my problem), then today I tried to boot into Windows 10 but failed.

I reached the screen with date and time shown. I remember if I click the mouse or hit the keyboard, it would turn to the login screen to let me login. But now the problem is my keyboard and mouse has no response. My screen is not a touch screen. I can do nothing. Other than the input devices, the machine seems to be running normally because I can see the time on the screen running.

My keyboard and mouse are both wireless using the same usb receiver. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The Windows drivers of your peripherals must be off for some reason. You should try pluging in a wired keyboard and mouse to log into your Windows account, and reach the Device Manager (Startup menu, type "Device Manager" it'll come up). Then look for a device that has a yellow exclamation mark on it, that might be the culprit.

You can try repairing it, or uninstalling the driver then reboot, both should do the trick. Make sure you have an internet connection then!

[EDIT] Your probably already tried this, but on Windows sometimes you just need to unplug/plug your receiver to another USB port

Comment: Yes, I've tried to unplug/plug to another USB port, but it doesn't fix the problem. I am now looking for a wired keyboard and mouse.